# Why does having cron run a remote command over ssh on a Cisco router get interrupted?

Tags: ssh, cisco

I have been tasked with making sure that if a particular server at work dies, we know about it right away. Because I'm not there (no one is really), I have written a script to run on my home router linux box (which runs Alpine Linux) to connect to our work Cisco router and ping the server (since the server is not directly accessible from the internet).

I have setup passwordless rsa on the Cisco router, and this is the main part of my script:

```
ssh user@work_router 'ping Server_IP' 2>/dev/null | grep -q ' 0 percent'

if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
    #It's not responding
else
    #Everything is fine
fi
```

The scripts works great when run manually, but when I tell cron to run it, it stops working.
Redirecting the ssh output to a logfile, I see this is the problem:

When running manually, the command gives this output:

```
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to SERVER_IP, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms
```

When cron runs it, this is the output:

```
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to SERVER_IP, timeout is 2 seconds:
!
```

Is there some reason why ping or ssh is getting interrupted before they complete running?

Edit:

Running Script from terminal using 'ssh -v -v':

http://pastebin.com/YXxbHq3t

Running Script with cron using 'ssh -v -v':

http://pastebin.com/wkYiAWsE

A vimdiff between these 2 files shows some interesting differences, but it's over my head. Can anyone tell what's going on?

Comment: The usual cause of `cron` commands working differently is that the environment is different (your `.bash_profile` etc. are not sourced, so PATH and other environment variables are different.) Is there anything in the script that could be unintentionally supplying data to `ssh` on stdin? `ssh` will by default read from stdin and send to the remote, without regard to what the remote might do with that input. If you give `ssh` the `-n` option, does that fix things?

Comment: I tried adding `-n`, but that did not help. The fact that the cron environment is different was my first thought, so I used [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2546509/4258196) to duplicate the cron environment and run the script. The script ran fine.